# Weird strtotime() issue - reading as incorrect format

Tags: php, date

The server's locale is set correctly, on other domains it seems to be fine... however I am currently experiencing a strange problem.

If I do a straight `strtotime('now');` it returns the right timestamp (for today's date/time in my timezone) however if I do:

```
strtotime('07/09/2012 13:48');
```

It returns a timestamp that's for 9th July, like it's reading the date as a US format. I've retrieved the timezone and it is set to Europe/London (by using date_default_timezone_get).

Any ideas?

Comment: Incorrect syntax, use strtotime() not strototime().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '07/09/2012 13:48');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) class and DateTime::createFromFormat() method.

Answer (score 0):

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) reads it as the US format. Best to use the ISO yyyy-mm-dd.

[See this for valid date formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)